Hibernation love story
When I was younger (about 7, 10 years ago) I watched a movie. It was a live action movie and in colour.
Stuff I remember about the plot:

Couple sitting in a car having a fight
The woman gets out and enters the grocery store
When she leaves the store with her shopping cart she's hit by a car
The man witnesses the incident
The woman falls into coma
He hibernates himself and asks to be woken up when she wakes up
He wakes up by himself

Character description:
He:

white
brown hair
western culture

She:

white
short brown hair

I watched the movie in German language so it might be a German production (but it's unlikely, I guess).

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? What time period was Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

We don't know how old you are! So "a young age" means nothing!

Could it be Forever Young with Mel Gibson from 1992? Plot is prety much the same, but I don't remember how she got into coma. He is military pilot and his friend military scientist created cryogenics machine. Gibson then asks him to freeze him for one year until his beloved one dies or something, but the test is then forgotten fo some reason, probably scientist dies. And in 1992 some kids playing in the military warehouse free him.
